# Grab the values of a select tag inside a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jstl

So what I have is a a for each loop in jsp file (or html) that is iterating over a set of data which is an array and in that loop I have a select tag that selects an option. This is suppose to display a row and each row has a select option. What I want to do is grab each instances of the value of the select tag. I tried doing this with JQuery with many different types of identifiers but no matter how i try to experiment it either returns nothing, undefined or the very first instance of the select tag but not the followings. Can anyone help me?

```
<c:forEach var="temp" items="${data}" id="loop">

    <tr><td>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle select" name="${temp.id}" >
            <option value="1" class="dropdown-item btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" > Pending </option>
            <option value="2" class="dropdown-item btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" > Approve </option>
            <option value="3" class="dropdown-item btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" > Deny </option>
        </select>
     </div>
     </td></tr>
</c:forEach>
/*****************************************************
                 JQuery Code
*****************************************************/
 $("#update").click(function() {
      var index = $("select.statues").val();
      console.log(index);
    /* $.each(index, function(i, item){
        console.log(item);
  });*/
});
```

The update id is an input tag that comes after all the html stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("select.statues").val();` get you the current selected option.

You will have to fetch all the selects first and iterate over them to get the corresponding value.

You are looking for

```
$("#update").click(function() {
   var $selects = $(".select");
   console.log($selects);
   $.each($selects, function(i, item) {
     // selected value
     var $currSelect = $(item)
     console.log($currSelect.val());
     // Selected option text
     console.log($currSelect.find('option:selected').text());
   });
 });
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z56d77um/4/)**

Comment: I am confuse, what exactly is this returning? I tried it out in my code and the browser console is telling me option (not options) is undefined.

Comment: I replaced options with `$selected` since they are technically selects.

Comment: Also the selector `$("select.statues")` is wrong. It has a class `select` but not `statuses`

Comment: Yeah the statues was a goof, I have it as statues class in my code but for some reason put select there

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank you so much. This is my first time ever doing JQuery and i hardly had any experience with JS so I am still a newbie so thank you again

Comment: One more question, does `var $selects = $(".select");`return an array of the select values? I ask because I need to pass this back to my server and iterate over the values there.

Comment: @anonuser1234 It returns all the elements with class `statuses` in your `HTML`. If you want to get the value you will have to iterate over them explicitly.